# Operar con valores de diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Tengo dos diccionarios que se caracterizan por lo siguiente:

```
# Mis datos:
dict_v = {1: ['12X58', '14X53'], 2: ['10X60']} 

dict_c = {1: ['8X58', '8X67', '10X49', '10X54', '10X60', '10X68', '10X77', '12X65', '12X72'], 
          2: ['8X58', '8X67', '10X49', '10X54', '10X60', '10X68', '10X77', '12X65', '12X72']}  

# Como en cada clave de dict_c, sus valores son iguales, entonces extraigo una lista ...
# ... para luego encontrar su longitud.

lista_c = []
for i in range(len(dict_c)):
        for j in dict_c[i+1]:
            if  (j in lista_c) == False: #--> De esta manera hago comparaciones y agrego cada vez los que faltan
                lista_c.append(j)
                
# Obtengo los valores necesarios para dict_c
numero_dict_c = len(lista_c) #--> Longitud de listado en común 
expo_dict_c = len(dict_c) #--> Respectivo exponente

# Obtengo los valores necesarios para dict_c
#cantidad_b = len(dict_v)

# FINALMENTE MI RESULTADO
Combinaciones_dict_c = ((len(lista_c))**expo_dict_c)

#Combinaciones_dict_v =
#CombinacionesTotales = 
#print('\n','El número máximo de combinaciones para este ejemplo es de: ',CombinacionesTotales)
```

1. Tienen en común la misma cantidad de claves.
2. El primero 'dict_v' posee valores diferentes en cada clave, mientras que el segundo, 'dict_c' posee los mismos valores para todas las claves.

Con esto, mi objetivo es calcular el número de combinaciones posibles por clave, involucrando los dos diccionarios, para ilustrar mejor tomemos el ejemplo de mi código, esto es justamente lo que busco:

```
Combinaciones_dict_c = 9^2 = 81

Combinaciones_dict_v = 2^1 * 1^1 = 2

CombinacionesTotales = 81 * 2 = 162
```

He logrado hacerlo para 'dict_c' extrayendo la lista de los elementos comunes, pero en 'dict_v' no he podido conseguirlo ya que el problema es que cada clave tiene diferentes valores.

Agradecería mucho la retroalimentación que me puedan brindar, saludos cordiales.

Comment: Con combinaciones posibles a que te refieres? Tener todas las combinaciones que puede haber entre un elemento y los otros de su lista, un elemento entre todos los valores diferentes entre los dos diccionarios, un elementos entre todos los valores de su diccionario o un elemnto entre todos la vlores entre los dos diccionarios? Por favor se más especifico. Saludos.

Comment: Las combinaciones de los dos diccionarios se operan por separado y sus resultados se multiplican para relacionar los dos, tal como en el ejemplo que ilustré: Para dict_c hay 9 elementos, elevo al cuadrado porque hay 2 claves y esos 9 elementos son los mismos para las dos claves. Ahora, para dict_v, hay 2 claves pero con valores distintos, entonces: primera clave: 2^1, segunda clave: 1^1, luego: 2*1 = 2. Si relaciono ahora dict_c, con dict_v, entonces: 81*2 = 162. Saludos, @gabrielcoronel.

Comment: Y que quieres hacer, osea pasar por pantalla todas las combinaciones o retornar un array con todas lodas combinaciones?

Comment: Solo pasar por pantalla el número de combinaciones posibles, que para este ejemplo tal como está serían 162, saludos. @gabrielcoronel

Comment: Lo he mirado y remirado y no le hallo la lógica (matemática) al problema ...